# Average velocity derivation

Tags: kinematics, velocity

Most of the time we make a mistake when calculating average velocity where
$$\bar v'=\frac {\sum v} n$$ but the actual is $\bar v=\frac {\sum s} {\sum t}$, can we use the wrong to get the correct ones?

Comment: What is $n$? What is the time dependence of the quantities you have written?

Comment: The former equation is correct and the latter equation is incorrect. Consider the velocities a, b, such that b = 101a. Suppose we run a for 99 seconds and b for 1 second. Sum of distances traveled is a*200s. Sum of times is 100 s. Thus, the average of a and 101 a is 2a? No, the average is 102a/2 = 51a.

Comment: @gs are you honestly suggesting that the average velocity of travelling a distance of a*200s in 100s is 51a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about how you define average. The formula $$ \bar{v} = \frac{\sum_i v_it_i}{\sum_i t_i}$$
is called a **weighted average** or a **weighted mean**, where times $t_i$ are the weights, as opposed to the arithmetic average/mean that is given by the first formula. In some contexts you need to use one, in some contexts the other. You can average over time (then you use the weighted average), or avarage over a sample (then the arithmetic average). For example you use the weighted average to calculate the average velocity of car that changes its speed, but you use the arithmetic average one to calculate the average velocity of all cars on the street.

In some cases you can use both formulae. That happens when you need to calculate the average velocity of a body that changes velocities, but the periods of time that the body travels with each particular velocity are all the same. We have then
$$ t_i = \frac{1}{n}T$$
and
$$ s_i = v_it_i =  \frac{1}{n}T v_i$$
Then
$$ \frac{\sum_i s_i}{\sum_i t_i} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}T\sum_i v_i}{T}= \frac{\sum_i v_i}{n}$$
In general, if all the wieights are eqaul, then the weighted average is equal to the arithmetic average.

In the oposite direction, if the time of the movement can be divided into equal periods such that in each of them the velocity is constant, then you can derive the formula using the weigthed mean from the formula using the arithmetic mean. Actually, even if the velocity is just almost constant (for example, if you divide the total time of movement into so many small periods that the change of velocity in each of them is negligible) it can be used approximately as well. If you take
$$ t_i = \frac{1}{n}T$$
$$ v_i = v\big(\frac{i}{n}T\big) $$
then $$ s_i \approx v_i t_i = v\big(\frac{i}{n}T\big)\frac{1}{n}T $$
and
$$ \sum_i s_i \approx \sum_i v\big(\frac{i}{n}T\big) \frac{1}{n}T = T \frac{\sum_i v\big(\frac{i}{n}T\big)}{n}$$
$$ \frac{\sum_i s_i}{T} = \frac{\sum_i v\big(\frac{i}{n}T\big)}{n}$$
It can also be added that you can take the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$ to get infinitesimaly small periods $t_i$; you'll get then the exact formula for $s$ expressed by an integral:
$$ s = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_i s_i = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_i v\big(\frac{i}{n}T\big) \frac{1}{n}T =: \int_0^T v(t) dt$$
and
$$ \bar{v} = \frac{s}{T} = \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T v(t) dt $$

Answer (score 0):

The average velocity is NOT given by V = (V1 + V2 +...+ Vn)/n,
since the velocities are vectors in different directions and the
acceleration is not always constant in different motions.

But, for this special case, in which if the begining and ending velocities for a motion are
known and the acceleration is constant, the average
velocity can also be expressed as V = (V1 + V2)/2 = Average speed.

If motion takes place in the same direction, then the average speed
and average velocity are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is the number of velocities (vector v, $\vec v$) in the summation then your first equation is only correct if the time intervals between taking velocity values are equal.  What you need is a time weighted average of the velocities, ie the velocity taken over a longer period of time counts for more in the average.

The second equation is correct provided that the sum is the sum of the displacements, ie $\langle \vec v\rangle =\text{average velocity}= \dfrac{\text{total displacement}}{\text{total time}}$